# Javascript rendering in tornado webserver

Tags: javascript, python, tornado, web.py

In following code snippet I'm trying to add JavaScript Files from Tornado server in HTML file in `<HEAD>` tag.

```
DEBUG_SCRIPTS = ''' <script src="src/main.js" type="text/javascript"></script> '''

class Entries(tornado.web.UIModule):
   def javascript_files(self):
     return 'src/main.js'

class MainHandler(tornado.web.RequestHandler):
   def get(self):
     params =  {}
     params['CORE_SCRIPTS'] = DEBUG_SCRIPTS
     path = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), 'index.html')
     self.render(path, params=params)
```

by `params['CORE_SCRIPTS'] = DEBUG_SCRIPTS` I was trying to add the `<script>` tag in HTML but it gets parsed in text which generates

`&lt;script type=&quot;text/javascript&quot; src=&quot;src/main.js&quot;&gt;&lt;/script&gt;`

So I came across `javascript_files()` method in [tornado specs](http://www.tornadoweb.org/documentation/web.html#tornado.web.UIModule) but I'm not getting any examples about its implementations. Can anyone help?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`javascript files` only works with [UIModules](http://www.tornadoweb.org/documentation/overview.html#ui-modules). Javascript files included that way are appended to the page just before the end of the body tag, though, not in the head tag.

If you really want the file included in the head tag, you can simply output the value of `params['CORE_SCRIPTS']` in the head tag of your template:

```
{% raw params['CORE_SCRIPTS'] %}
```

Comment: thanks mahn! Its working. But even though I did with `javascript_files` its not appending to the body. Do you know any example of implementation? and 2nd point what does '%' (I mean the difference between '%' n '{}') and 'raw' means over here?

Comment: There's an example in the UIModules documentation I linked to. You need to actually use the module in the template, e.g. `{% module Entries(entry) %}`.

Comment: As to your second question: `{{ foo }}` outputs a variable in a template, `{% foo %}` call function foo.